# Access asset_host inside javascript for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have the following javascript (shortened for clarity):

```
$modal = $('<img src="/assets/loading.gif">');
$('body').append($modal);
```

But I am not sure how to access the asset_host within that javascript?  Any suggestions?  (I am trying to not use coffee script)

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

---

[**asset_path**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html)

If you're not accessing the file inside the asset pipeline (and consequently can use `ERB` code), you could use this:

```
$img = '<%=j image_tag asset_path("loading.gif)" %>'
$('body').append($img);
```

---

[**Gon**](https://github.com/gazay/gon)

If you are accessing inside the asset pipeline (where you can only use pure JS), you'll have to pass the asset host variable to JS through HTML. Gon is a great way to do this:

```
#config/initializers/gon.rb
gon.push({asset_host: ActionController::Base.asset_host})

#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= include_gon %>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$modal = $('<img src="' + gon.asset_host + '/assets/loading.gif">');
$('body').append($modal);
```

Got the [asset_host reference from here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html)